# Nothing happen when running the code

Tags: vba, web-services, excel

Hi guys this is my code

But when I run it nothing happen, apparently it runs well in break mode (debug).
What can I do ? cheers

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button2_Click()

    Dim i&, j&, n& 'as Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet 

    n = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
          For i = 1 To n
               Select Case .Cells(i, "A").Value2 
                    Case "2015 Xor 2011":   .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "blue"
                    Case "2001 Xor 2003":   .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "green"
                    Case "2014 Xor 2006":   .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "red"
               End Select
               j = j + 1
          Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Which is supposed to fill the B column by colours'name regarding year found in the A column

Comment: what is the value of n before for loop ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just Dim i, j, n instead

Comment: You have there "End With" statement without starting it

Comment: In what conditions do you want to fill cell B1 with blue color? If there is text '2015 Xor 2011' in cell A1? If there is just number 2015 in A1? If there is number 2011 in A1?

Comment: And also what is the use of incrementing j in the for loop ?

Comment: @mauekuna I just forgot to put it in the post, n valu is the length of the column I use 6 cells for a test but the real file is about 20k rows

Comment: @mielk id like to fill cell B1 if there is 2015 or 2011 is cell A1

Comment: Should the cell in column B be cleared if there is no matching year in column A (possibly from previous values)?

Comment: @Jeeped it alsways will have a matching in the A column

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the *j* var comes into play; I would imagine that it is involved with some code deemed unimportant to this question that was removed.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    With Ws
        n = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To n
             Select Case .Cells(i, "A").Value2
                Case 2015, 2011
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "blue"
                Case 2001, 2003
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "green"
                Case 2014, 2006
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = "red"
             End Select
             j = j + 1
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

The [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) can handle [Xor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6.aspx) comparisons with a comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. You said that there is about 20K rows, so all the calculations are made on arrays for better performance.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim years As Variant
    Dim colors() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    '------------------------------------------------------


    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet


    'Read the values from column A to array - it will make the calculations faster.
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        years = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))
    End With


    'Resize [colors] array to adjust its size to the size of [years] array.
    ReDim colors(LBound(years, 1) To UBound(years, 1), 1 To 1)
    For i = LBound(years, 1) To UBound(years, 1)
        Select Case years(i, 1)
             Case 2015, 2011:   colors(i, 1) = "blue"
             Case 2001, 2003:   colors(i, 1) = "green"
             Case 2014, 2006:   colors(i, 1) = "red"
        End Select
    Next i


    'Paste the result array back into the worksheet
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(years) - LBound(years) + 1, 1) = colors


End Sub
```

Comment: @ulysse-pacomekoudou A couple of things: 1) There was no `With Ws` opening statement. 2) When you make a case block like that `Case "2015 Xor 2011"` you don't check if this cell is equal 2015 or 2011; in fact you check if this cell contain text '2015 Xor 2011'.